# What is the surface tension of liquids in space?

Tags: surface-tension

I mean does surface tension exists in space on liquids?

Let's take an example if I have to write something using ballpen in space and space does not have gravity. Does it works because of the surface tension?

Comment: A ballpoint may not work, but the [space pen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Pen) will! At least if one is to believe [The Pen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0697749/) episode of Seinfeld...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface tension does exist "in space", which I take you to mean "without gravity". Surface tension in liquids is simply the attractive interactions between the molecules of a liquid. That exists whether there is gravity or not. I think most pens will not work well without being in the proper orientation in gravity, though. If you try using a normal ballpoint pen and write on a paper on the ceiling, you'll probably find that it won't work because gravity is pushing the ink in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. That's what I thought most of the ballpoints don't work because it was never designed to work in space.
Lets assume that it is working in space, does the ink still flows down just because of surface tension phenomenon and not because of gravity ? 
I find surface tension plays insignificant role where there is no gravity.